# Why would a candidate hide one or more than one previous employers name?

Tags: resume

In a US located company's Front end engineer candidate's resume (he is at Costa Rica), I saw a candidate list his 3 most recent previous experience position's company name are generic "IT Company".
Is that a popular practice to do nowadays, maybe somehow a popular thing to do in oversea / central America? If not, how should I think about this candidate?

Comment: Sounds like a non-native speaker got a resume template from the Internet and failed to list the actual company name. Either that or they're trying to trick you. There's no way for me to tell you what's going on. You can either call the person and do a brief phone interview or move on to other candidates. Remember, it's not your problem that their resume sucks and does not put their best foot forward.

Comment: There are plenty of companies who don't want to be mentioned, at least not in any way that tells anyone what they are doing. Or as MonkeyZeus said, a form filled out incorrectly. Or someone given bad advice how to fill this out. But instead of overthinking it, ask the candidate.

Comment: "Why would a candidate hide one or more than one previous employers name?"  If they did not explain this in their cover letter or anywhere else on their resume, the only way to know is to ask them.

Comment: Is it possible that the candidate worked for a consulting firm and that the client names are confidential ? I worked for an IT consulting firm around 1990, and in that firm's standard CV template the convention was to not name the clients we had worked for as consultants. The phrasing would be something like "August-December 1990: Manufacturing firm - I participated in the transition from PDP-11 to VAX."

Comment: @Nimloth: I would still expect a resume to name the consulting firm itself, assuming you're applying for an external position and not for a transfer within the consulting firm.

Answer (score 3):

> Is that a popular practice to do nowadays

No

I can't think of any good reason to do this with multiple company names. The purpose of a Resume is to give concise information, especially anything that has to do with prior experience or is otherwise relevant to the job applied for.

Comment: They could be companies one might find objectionable, such as gambling or pornography.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane you would call a porn company an 'IT company' in that situation?